# Checking if every parameter of a stored procedure got default value or not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

How would you implement that check? You have N parameters for a stored procedure.

If all value are null or 0 or empty string, run the code else skip it

This is how I implemented it, is there a better way?

I really don't like what I did so I'm open to any better idea, must be easily maintainable since it would be done at many places

```
    declare @doRunIt bit
    declare @checkAllNull varchar(max)
    declare @sumOfInt int

    set @checkAllNull = ''
    set @checkAllNull = @checkAllNull + coalesce(@param1,'')
    set @checkAllNull = @checkAllNull + coalesce(@param2,'')
    set @checkAllNull = @checkAllNull + coalesce(@param3,'')
    set @checkAllNull = @checkAllNull + coalesce(@param4,'')
    set @checkAllNull = @checkAllNull + coalesce(@param5,'')
    set @checkAllNull = @checkAllNull + coalesce(@param6,'')

    set @sumOfInt = coalesce(@param7,0)+coalesce(@param8,0)+
                    coalesce(@param9,0)+coalesce(@param10,0)+
                    coalesce(@param11,0)+coalesce(@param12,0)

    set @checkAllNull = @checkAllNull + cast(@sumOfInt as varchar(max))



    if ( isnumeric(@checkAllNull)=1 )
        if (cast(@checkAllNull as int) > 0)
            set @doRunIt = 1
        else
            set @doRunIt = 0
    else
        if (ltrim(rtrim(@checkAllNull)) <> '')
            set @doRunIt = 1
        else
            set @doRunIt = 0
```

End goal is to move the check made in code for inserting empty row, if all parameters are null or using default value, in the DB into the stored procedure, so other apps can call the same stored procedure without having to deal with checking for empty row.

Comment: You may be going about this from the wrong direction. Since you stated that the solution "must be easily maintainable since it would be done at many places" I'm guessing that you think there is a fundamental issue with the database. Since this seems like an unusual request to me I'm thinking there might be a better/completely different way to handle your concern.

What are you really trhing to do, and why?

Comment: @Scott Bruns, I updated my question

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have to cope with e.g. `@param7` = 19, `@param11` = -19 (which together with the other int parameters, would still sum to zero).

Comment: Fredou, How often are apps calling the stored procedure with all parameters set to null/defaults? I can only think of one app I've worked on that had a query that performed poorly if all nulls/defaults were passed. IS that the nature of most of your queries? At this point I'm mostly just curious to learn about something different.

Comment: @Scott Bruns, without going into details, we currently have a screen that can accept many different kind of information each kind of information is grouped into many textbox/combobox/etc and each group got a storeproc. right now, even if there is nothing in a group, the storeproc will be called on a save action which will trigger an insert with everything being null or default value. right now the code cannot be modified but the sql(storeproc) can.

Comment: Fredou, Thanks for the explanation. It does sound like you have an interesting system and a real need for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
DECLARE @IsValid BIT = dbo.IsValidParameter(@param1) & 
                       dbo.IsValidParameter(@param2) & 
                       dbo.IsValidParameter(@param3) & 
                       dbo.IsValidParameter(@param4)
```

Helper function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsValidParameter(@p1 Sql_Variant)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF @p1 IS NULL OR @p1 = '' OR @p1 = 0
        RETURN 0    
    RETURN 1    
END
GO
```

Comment: sadly for an unknown reason, any UDF on the sql cluster that we use have some kind of weird issue where it can hang for a few seconds while eating all the cpu and blocking the cluster.

Comment: @Fredou put it in a SP than Or fix your server :-)

Comment: i would really really really like the second choice but i have no info or control over them

Comment: Fredou, did you actually try this solution? Maybe you'll get lucky and it will work for some reason.